# 'No medium found' after issuing dd on an old external hard drive

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, external-hdd, dd

I'm trying to format an old external hard drive. It doesn't pop up in `gparted`.

It does get detected though:

`dmesg` output:

```
[20022.409487] usb 2-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 13 using ehci-pci
[20022.538837] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0930, idProduct=0b09
[20022.538843] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[20022.538847] usb 2-1.2: Product: USB 3.5"-HDD
[20022.538850] usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: TOSHIBA
[20022.538853] usb 2-1.2: SerialNumber: 001d93cc
[20022.541204] usb-storage 2-1.2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[20022.541889] scsi host6: usb-storage 2-1.2:1.0
[20023.558459] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Sunplus  USB2SATA bridge  0407 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[20023.558974] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[20023.561919] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

`lsusb` output:

```
Bus 002 Device 013: ID 0930:0b09 Toshiba Corp. PX1396E-3T01 External hard drive
```

I read somewhere that I should `dd` the device with zero's, but that fails as well:

```
$ sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb
dd: failed to open '/dev/sdb': No medium found
```

Is there anything I can try before throwing it out of the window?

Comment: It may be worth the trouble to reboot with the external drive connected, if you haven't already done so. I've seen USB drives being suddenly recognized, or their parameters changed, after a reboot.

Comment: The `dmesg` output shows that the kernel thinks it's a removable disk (like a floppy, magneto-optical, or similar device). Googling suggests that's a USB-to-SATA adapter device. I suggest you try re-plugging the USB/SATA connector, since it may be loose. Also check to be sure the disk is powered, and try it on another computer or OS. If you're convinced the hardware is OK, try the *latest* Ubuntu (17.04); it could be an older kernel has bugs that prevent it from working with this device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turned out that I was using a bad power supply. Make sure you use a proper power supply.

Answer (score 19):

In my case I was trying to do:

- Insert USB stick
- Unmount automatically mounted partition
- Try `sudo dd if=/mnt/d/instalki/OS/bionicpup32-8.0-uefi.iso of=/dev/sdb`

The error occured only when I unmounted USB stick clicking in file manager GUI. After unmounting by `sudo umount /dev/sdb1` dd executed without complaint.

Comment: This is the real answer. Don't toss something in the bin because of a Linux quirk. Eject is *not* umount and I had this issue before with something unrelated (forgot what). Ejecting removes the device node, unmounting doesn't.

Comment: Just for others: same issue here, GUI umount did not do it, `gparted` umount did.(edit: it totally f's up by usb hub though... I guess the other mentions about it being suspect are quite true as well)

Answer (score 4):

Most of the times the "**No medium found**" error which is same as "**No media**" label shown on some GUIs means that the hdd is damaged. I tried to "repair" such disks once, I followed every guide I found on the web, I used several OS but nothing could be done...

So, my advice is "**throw it in the recycle bin**" (not from the window) and spend your time with something else!

Comment: No need to throw it away - the see the other answer about unmounting properly which worked for me.

Comment: I -1'ed this answer because it seemed overly certain that this one possible explanation is *the* explanation... while that's still true, I ran into a similar problem where a microSD card became read-only in some strange genuine hardware failure way, so I would gladly flip my vote now if I could.

Answer (score 0):

Your disk medium may not well attached with the disk box, check it carefully,
replug if required.